# A subtle line appears within our homepage banner, situated near the header section

Tags: header, elementor

i am seeing this line on header, how to remove it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm5gI.jpg)

i designed this landing page in elemontor , joogloo.com
failed to make the header mobile friendly and also want to remove this line see in Screenshot,
free suggestions are welcomed! Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.